# Overriding spring properties in test with computed values

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I know I can use `@TestPropertySource`. But annotations accept only literals. what if i want to compute the values or even if i want to compute which properties i want to override. is it doable in spring? how can i register arbitrary properties in spring's `Environment` in tests?

Comment: Not sure, but are you looking for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: What about `System.setProperty("myproperty", "foo");` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144312/1199132

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to load up a configuration object. By encapsulating the configuration you can compute the values to use in test profile.

Comment: i know how to use profiles but how can i load/build a configuration object that compute property names and values?

Comment: Can you give me a use case?

Comment: i want to read user's local config (ignored by git) that tells on which port user has local database. and then use that port to configure datasource in spring tests

Comment: This sounds exactly the problem profiles solve. Whenever I had a local environment that differs from the other environments, I commit a local profile, then add it to git ignore. That way everyone picks it up and can modify it without impacting others.