# is there a way to push environment variables when using org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have this test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;


@SpringBootTest
class ThisTestClass {

@Test
void contextLoads() {}

}
```

when contextLoads(), a pice of code as following is triggered

```
private String envVar = System.getenv("ENV_VAR");
```

which is returning null, which is messing with my test, therefore I need a way to push environment variables at some point of time before executing this test. doing this via the IDE env settings or the console is not an option, since this is going to be executed by jenkins as well.

I have tryed:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"ENV_VAR = some_var"})
```

and

```
    static {
    System.setProperty("ENV_VAR", "some_var");
    }
```

without any luck, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variable or system property in spring tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306951/how-to-set-environment-variable-or-system-property-in-spring-tests)

Comment: Hey, no, TestPropertySource did not worked either. I was trying that after writing the question.

for now the only strategi I am considering is stop using System.getenv

Answer (score 1):

Both should work...

- set environment variable via static initialization
- set environment variable via properties

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "bar = foo" , "foobar = foobar"} )
class SoTestEnvironmentVariablesApplicationTests {

    static {
        System.setProperty("foo","bar");
    }

    @Autowired Environment environment;

    @Test
    void loadEnvironmentVariables() {
        assertNotNull(environment);
        assertEquals("bar" , environment.getProperty("foo"));
        assertEquals("foo" , environment.getProperty("bar"));
        assertEquals("foobar" , environment.getProperty("foobar"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Dirk, thanks for your answer.

It is not working.still the same error

Comment: @FacundoLaxalde above code is working [ref github](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/push-environment-variables-in-test/blob/master/src/test/java/so/demo/pushenvironmentvariablesintest/PushEnvironmentVariablesInTestApplicationTests.java)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. `System.getenv("ENV_VAR")` is different than `environment.getProperty("ENV_VAR")`