# How do I add environment variables in IntelliJ Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I Am trying to add an environmental variable inside my spring-boot `application.properties` file. I know how to add it normally on a *non spring-boot project*, but I cannot find the field for adding environment variables, this is all I see:

[image: this is all I see]

This is my application.properties file, this may help.

```ini
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FTHLDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASS}
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: what do you mean by "environmental variable" ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The UI of Run/Debug Configurations has changed. Under 'Modify Options' select 'Environment Variables' under 'Operating System'.

[image: Screenshot of explanation]

Answer (score 1):

`run` -> `Edit Configurations` -> edit environment variables.
[image]

Comment: ..and separate the variables using ;

Answer (score 0):

you can write the environment variable name directly with it's value like this
myvariable = its value
inside the application.properties file
and to use it just inject it inside your method or globally inside your class like this `public class MyClass{ @Value("${myvariable}"} String myvariable;  }`

Answer (score 0):

- Edit Configuration -> Environment Variables -> Add your .env variables here..

Like:

- My `.env` file
  [image]
- Edit Configuration -> Environment Variables
  [image]