# Configure spring to connect to mysql over ssl

Tags: spring, ssl, jdbc, c3p0, spring-jdbc

I am connecting to MySQL over SSL from my Java application. I have configured MYSQL to support SSL and generated client certificates. I have imported server CA certificate and client certificate into keystore. This is how my code currently looks like

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MySampleDb? verifyServerCertificate =true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true"

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/home/cert/keystore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/cert/truststore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

I want to use spring with C3p0 to connect to MYSQL over SSL.This is my spring configuration file which reads parameters from jdbc.properties.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    ........
</bean>
```

How can I configure spring to set properties 
**verifyServerCertificate =true

useSSL=true

requireSSL=true"**
Also is it possible to set **keyStore and trustStore** values in spring config file.

Answer (score 15):

The value for `jdbc.url` in jdbc.properties has to be

> jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MySampleDb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true

Those parameters must be added directly to the URL for MySQL. The parameters for `keyStore` and `trustStore` should be passed to the JVM at start like so:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path_to_truststore_file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

You *can* [use Spring to set system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340970/131929) but I'd never use it, it's too cumbersome.

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessary to pass `keyStore` and `trustStore` to `java` program or set any system properties as it can be achieved via connection properties per connection!

So you can use different certificated for different connections (and applications if you are in app server).

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879119/173149 Relevant part:

> jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/MYDB?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/keystore.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456

It is documented:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the **useSSl**, **requireSSL**, and **verifyServerCertificate** properties of a `DataSource` by using Java based configuration.  The `addDataSourceProperty` method of the `DataSource` class gives you the ability, as shown in the below code snippet (you can replace HikariDataSource with a C3p0 instance)

MySQL Connector/J exposes configuration properties for key stores (e.g. `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl`), so I assume that `addDataSourceProperty` can be used for these properties too.

I do not know if the XML configuration schema provides a tag that corresponds to `addDataSourceProperty`.

```
public DataSource createPslDataSource(final MyDataSourceProperties myDataSourceProperties) {

    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", true);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("requireSSL", true);
    dataSource.addDataSourceProperty("verifyServerCertificate", true);

    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(myDataSourceProperties.getJdbcUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(myDataSourceProperties.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(myDataSourceProperties.getPassword());

    return dataSource;
}
```