# Configure Wildfly to use SSL connection for MariaDB

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, wildfly, wildfly-13

I want to configure Wildfly 14 to use encrypted JDBC connection. I tried this:

MariaDB:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE USER 'wildfly' IDENTIFIED BY 'qwerty';
CREATE DATABASE production_gateway;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON production_gateway.* TO 'wildfly'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Create certificate:

```
mkdir -p /etc/mysql/ssl
cd /etc/mysql/ssl

sudo openssl genrsa 4096 > ca-key.pem
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 36500 -key ca-key.pem -out cacert.pem
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -days 36500 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
sudo openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
sudo openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 36500 -CA cacert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem

sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 36500 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
sudo openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
sudo openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 36500 -CA cacert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
openssl verify -CAfile cacert.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem
```

Add certificate in MariDB under my.cnf

```
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/cacert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
```

systemctl restart mysql

Import certificate in Java keystone:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/

openssl x509 -outform der -in /etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem -out certificate.der

keytool -import -alias client -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -file certificate.der -srcstorepass changeit
```

Export keystone configuration:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit"
```

When I use this connection link:

`jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/production_gateway` - it's working

But when I use: `jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/production_gateway?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true`

I get:

```
17:40:30,454 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
17:40:30,472 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("test-connection-in-pool") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "MariaDB")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

Can you advice how I can fix this issue?
I use JDBC driver `mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`

Comment: Never tried it. But wouldn't &requireSSL have to be &requireSSL=true ?

Comment: Sorry, typo mistake.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277264 this link might help you

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge,you just need to provide `requireSSL` field to `true`.

Try with below line :

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/production_gateway?requireSSL=true
```

Let us know whether it's working or not.

For more clarification you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523595/specify-ssl-to-be-used-for-jdbc-in-context-xml) .