# spring jpa application.properties useSSL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to turn off ssl, to my local mysql database.
But I cannot find the actual property in a spring application.properties file that would do this.

my current file is:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "test"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = blah

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I have tried `spring.datasource.useSSl=false` and that does not work. I have also tried `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test&useSSL=false`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to turn off SSL as it's disabled by default ([you have to add `useSSL=true` to your JDBC url and configure several properties to enable it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for the reply. I know about using `useSSL=true` which at a later time I will be using. However, my question was how do I add `useSSL=true/false` in a spring application.properties file. You cannot add it to the datasource.url which I have tried, see above.

Answer (score 50):

I fixed my issue with the below:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be using '?' instead of '&'

This is yours

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test&useSSL=false
```

What I'm saying is

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like to pollute `java` options or system properties, which are useless in application containers in any case...

You can set SSL certificate for MySQL connection programmically with:

> jdbc:mysql://example.com:3306/MYDB?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/keystore.jks&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:cert/truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=123456

It is documented:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

If you still looking for that, then here is answear:

[How to add datasource url query parameters as application.properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148356/how-to-add-datasource-url-query-parameters-as-application-properties)

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useSSL=false
```