# How to add datasource url query parameters as application.properties?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

Is it possible to add datasource url parameters as an extra property? Or do I always have to append them directly to the url as query parameters?

Example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useSSL=false&tinyInt1isBit=false
```

I'd prefer adding them, pseudocode:

```
spring.datasource.url.meta.useSSL=false
spring.datasource.url.meta.tinyInt1isBit=false
```

Possible somehow?

Comment: Which spring boot version and datasource are you using.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Check this out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html find #DATASOURCE section. There are no more options after datasource.url

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using most recent `spring-boot` version, and `mysql` as ds.

Comment: Mysql is your database NOT your DataSource. Need to know the implementation as with Hikari you can pass properties with spring.datasource.hikari.datasource-propertie.<name>=value

Comment: Sorry, you're right. `Hikari` is my ds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the hint of @M. Deinum, the following works:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useSSL=false
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.tinyInt1isBit=false
```

Comment: you can accept your answer to indicate issue got solved