# How to make the connection between the mysql database and springboot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have made a table persons in a schema name test_schema. I have connected the database from DATABASE > CONNECT TO DATABASE in mysql workbench. Then I tried to connect with that but that doesn't seem to work somehow. 
BTW I have cloned it from github and trying to run my database in here.

I have tried to see the status but that shows running but the data is not fetching from the database.

application.yml

````
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persons
    username: root
    password: users
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: null
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true```
````

UsersRepository.java

```
package com.techprimers.db.repository;

import com.techprimers.db.model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
}
```

Users.java

```
package com.techprimers.db.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "token")
    private String token;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "post")
    private Integer post;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Integer post) {
        this.post = post;
    }


}
```

UsersResources.java

```
package com.techprimers.db.resource;

import com.techprimers.db.model.Users;
import com.techprimers.db.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UsersResource {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<Users> getAll() {
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

SpringBootMysqldbApplication.java

```
package com.techprimers.db;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.techprimers.db.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMysqldbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMysqldbApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The result should have been the table elements but instead the  Whitelabel Error Page is showing. I don't know what I have been doing wrong since there is nothing much to do. I just modified the code according to my needs but I think I somehow messed with the database connection or I am doing the database connection wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope that your database credentials are correct. try adding @Repository annotation above your UsersRepository class. otherwise you can't autowire UsersRepository.

Comment: @Vimukthi_R Still not working . My database credentials are right there is no problem regarding that. The username and password are correct.

Comment: Are you getting any error or exception ?

Comment: @Vimukthi_R Nothing,it is running and executing like there is no error . Only the response is not the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet but I think your database enforces ssl by default Since MySQL 5.7.5, but it is not obligatory for clients by default. Check this url please jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persons?useSSL=false

As Avi mentioned, If your database is test_schema write it in the url instead of persons

And please, provide errors and exceptions right in the question if there any

[Link how to handle ssl in mysql](https://scalegrid.io/blog/configuring-and-managing-ssl-on-your-mysql-server/)

[Stackoverflow spring and mysql ssl question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576994/spring-jpa-application-properties-usessl)

Comment: There is no error or exception even after running those codes. That's what making this more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to notice that you said TABLE NAME IS "PERSONS", but in url you have mentioned that as DB name

> jdbc:mysql://${DB_SERVER_NAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASE}:currentSchema=${DB_SCHEMA};

which is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db-name>`

Check that once