# How can I define a Java system property in a Spring XD stream?

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-xd

For some ad hoc testing of a custom Spring XD processor, I would like to specify a Java system property during the definition of the stream to be passed to the processor. Is this possible?

Comment: You can access java system property at any moment (processor included) with `System.getProperty()`

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I want to set one during the definition of my stream. Is that possible? Do i have to tweak one of the module's configuration XMLs?

Comment: Here's how you set System properties from XML and from Java : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3340970/4140367