# Use of SystemPropertyInitializer to set System Property before setting property placeholder

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, system-properties, property-placeholder

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690492/167745), you can use the Spring Batch class `org.springframework.batch.support.SystemPropertyInitializer` to set a System Property during startup of a Spring Context.

In particular, I was hoping to be able to use it to set `ENVIRONMENT` because part of Spring Batch config reads:

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

But `SystemPropertyInitializer` uses `afterPropertiesSet()` to set the System Property, and apparently this happens *after* the configuration of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to pass in the environment property as a command-line argument, so it can be resolved as a system property.

If that's not an option you can implement a `ApplicationContextInitializer` that promotes environment properties to system properties.

```
public class EnvironmentPropertyInitializer implements 
                   ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    boolean override = false; //change if you prefer envionment over command line args

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        for (Entry<String, String> environmentProp : System.getenv().entrySet()) {
            String key = environmentProp.getKey();
            if (override || System.getProperty(key) == null) {
                System.setProperty(key, environmentProp.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here it looks like you're using Spring Batch Admin, so you can register your initializer with a slight addition to the [`web.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-resources/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml) file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>org.your.package.EnvironmentPropertyInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

**Adding Background Since a Comment Didn't Seem Sufficient:** Here's the relevant classes and the order in which they are called/evaluated.

1. The `ApplicationContextInitializer` tells the Spring Application how to load an application context and can be used to set bean profiles, and change other aspects of the context. This gets executed *before* the context gets completely created.
2. The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and calls `postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)`. This modifies the `BeanFactory` to allow for resolution of properties like `${my.property:some.default}` when setting the properties of a bean as it is created by the `BeanFactory`.
3. The `SystemPropertyInitializer` implements `InitializingBean` and calls `afterPropertiesSet()`. This method runs after a bean is instantiated and the properties have been set.

So you're right that the `SystemPropertyInitializer` will not help here since it evaluates after the properties are set on the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. The `ApplicationContextInitializer`, however, will be able to promote those environment properties to system properties so they can be interpreted by the XML.

And one more note that I forgot to mention, one of the first declared beans will need to be:

```
 <context:property-placeholder/>
```

Though it seems redundant, it will allow your `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to evaluate `${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}` correctly by using the environment properties you just promoted.

Comment: I'm not sure how applicable the difference between a System Property and an Environment Property is. The class `SystemPropertyInitializer` is calling `System.setProperty()` within its code. What's I'm running into is that it does not get called until *after* the `placeholderProperties` is resolved. Would not the same problem be experienced with this solution? I'm not confident enough with my Spring lifecycle knowledge.

Comment: added detail above (too long for a comment)