# Is there a way to move Java VM args to Spring Boot configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, https

I use ssl to acces to my database, I have some configuration in JAVA JVM Args.

Is there a way to move these configuration into spring configuration file (My config are in **application.yml**) ?

JVM args that I want to move are :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password>
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add JVM arguments for SSL properties in the application.yml file like this :

```
 server:    
      ssl:
          key-store: /path/to/keystore
          key-store-password: <password>
          trust-store: /path/trust/store
          trust-store-password: <password>
```

Common properties that can use in Spring properties file are defined here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: This is not equivalent to setting the JVM properties. These properties are for configuring the key store and trust store for the embedded web server (e.g. Tomcat) only. The JVM properties are used to set the default `SSLContext` for the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the properties to take effect, they need to be in the system `Properties` object before the SSL classes are initialized.

The chances are that if you attempt put them into the Spring config file, and (somehow) transfer them to the system `Properties` object, they won't get there soon enough.

Having said that ... the following Q&A explains how to inject new properties:

- [Set System Property With Spring Configuration File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339736/set-system-property-with-spring-configuration-file)

(Read all of the Answers.)