# Create own configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to have my own configuration property: `isRegistrationEnabled=false`. I want to check it and change in my controllers. How to easily do this in spring?

Comment: can you be helped by reading this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339736/set-system-property-with-spring-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

If you want some variable to check AND change it then use simple variable.
Configuration properties are values used to configure application on startup not to modify them in a runtime for example database password. Its only needed on startup and won't change in a runtime additionaly you can alter this without changing code providing flexibility.

Comment: Thank you. Variable is good idea if I want this property in one class. But I want access for it in 2 different controllers. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can create a bean with this variable and inject it in those 2 controllers or use static variable.